# Where can download VSTS Service Pack 1 Install?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008, service-pack

Where can download the offline installer of the  Visual Studio Team System SP1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an offline installer, but there is an [ISO download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=27673C47-B3B5-4C67-BD99-84E525B5CE61&displaylang=en).

Comment: Actually it is the offline installer :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?  This is the server side update

[Service Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9E40A5B6-DA41-43A2-A06D-3CEE196BFE3D&displaylang=en)